# PHP: Check select value and textbox != NULL

Tags: php, html, if-statement

This might be a silly question but I've got brainfreeze right now..

**HTML**

```
<b>Comment</b><br>
<select name="text" id="text">
    <option value="">Select a option</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<div class="other box">
    <b>Comment 2</b><br>
    <input type="text" name="own_text">
</div>
```

If someone select value "other" from the select I also want to make sure the textbox (own_text) not are NULL, with PHP.

**Tried**

```
if($_POST['text'] == "other" && $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'Go on';
} else {
    echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
}
```

With this code I've got the error message (You chose other but has not typed anything) even if I chose "option1" or "option2", why? If I chose "option1" or "option2" it shall tell me the other message (Go on).

Thanks in advance! :)

**Solution (thanks Olvathar)**

```
if($_POST['text'] != "other" || $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'Go on';
} else {
        echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing select "other" to continue, try this

```
if($_POST['text'] != "other" || $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'Go on';
 } else {
     echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
 }
```

Comment: it will show `go on` if you select `other` and leave `own_text` as empty

Comment: This one was the easiest solution in my case. Thank you so much mate. :D

Comment: oops sorry. as you said just at glance it look wrong. but it is perfect.

Comment: @Treps , @Olvathar When you selected an option `!=other` and no value in text box , what will be the result...??

Comment: When you select and option different to 'other' the result will be 'Go on'. Doesn't matter what own_text value is @SherinJose

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if($_POST['text'] == "other" && $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'Go on';
} else if($_POST['text'] == "other" && $_POST['own_text'] == "") {{
    echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
}else if($_POST['text'] != "other")
{
  // do other things
}
```

because if you just mention else it will also have condition where $_POST['text'] is not selected as other

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if($_POST['text'] == "other"){
    if($_POST['own_text'] != "") {
        echo 'Go on';
    } else {
        echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
    }
}
else{
    if($_POST['text']!=''){
        echo 'Go on';
    }
    else{
        echo 'You must select an option !';
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(  ($_POST['text'] == "other" || empty($_POST['text'])) && $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'Go on';
} else if ($_POST['text'] != "other") {
    echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
}
```

Comment: you change the value
<option value="anyValueThisAppearsINphp">Other</option>

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['text'] == "other" && $_POST['own_text'] == "") {
   echo 'You chose other but has not typed anything';
} else if($_POST['text'] == "other" && $_POST['own_text'] != "") {
    echo 'You chose other and typed something'; 
} else {
    echo 'go on';
}
```